# How do i add an additional fee to the totalprice

Tags: prestashop, fee

my question is how do i add an additional fee to the totalprice of the  Prestashop 1.7 cart.
how can i do it?

the additional fee have to be everywhere -> invoice (extra row before shipping), the order history page, confirmation email.

can someone help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, on SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 0):

You should use "handling charges" field in Shipping > Preferences.